# Blender Cube to Unity 3D Terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I made a floating Island in blender and exported it as a FBX file to unity. Is there a way to terrain paint grass, trees etc.. onto the island inside of Unity 3D? I used a cube to make the island in blender and probably wouldn't like to use a plane mesh to create a floating island.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object2Terrain](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Object2Terrain&_ga=2.237319816.985921527.1576594815-722469399.1575460859) to convert your mesh to a heightmap to use in unity.

Comment: that sort of works but only works for the top part and doesnt form to the bottom of the floating lsland. If it was a sphere only half the sphere would be a terrain and not a full sphere